# App Keeps crashing with just_audio and just_audion_background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am developing an app that includes playing audio from url. Unfortunately, the app keeps crashing every time i try to play an audio. below is my code:

I create AudioSource instance then i send it as a parameter into another widget

```
final audioSource = AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse(video["audio"]),
        tag: MediaItem(
          id: 1.toString(),
          album: audio["subCategory"]["name"],
          title: audio["title"],
          artUri: Uri.parse(
            audio["image"],
          ),
        ),
      );

Navigator.push(
        context,
        SlideRightRoute(
          page: AudioPlayPage(
            audios: widget.videos,
            categoryImage: video["subCategory"]["image"],
            category: audio["subCategory"]["name"],
            initialAudio: video,
            url: audio["audio"],
            image: audio["image"],
            title: audio["title"],
            audio: audioSource,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

On the next page, I have function below which i call in the initState method:

```
Future<void> _init() async {
    await _player.setAudioSource(widget.audio);
}
```

then listen to to player as below

```
StreamBuilder<SequenceState?>(
          stream: _player.sequenceStateStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data;
            if (state?.sequence.isEmpty ?? true) {
              return Container(
                height: getScreenHeight(context) * 0.37,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            theme_color().withOpacity(0.7),
                            Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.7)
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // PlayLottie(_player),
                    Positioned(
                        top: 25,
                        left: 5,
                        child: leading(context, null, null, theme_color())),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 15,
                      child: Container(
                        width: getScreenWidth(context),
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            end: Alignment.topCenter,
                            // stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 1],
                            colors: [
                              tv_black(),
                              tv_black().withOpacity(0.8),
                              tv_black().withOpacity(0.6),
                              tv_black().withOpacity(0.4),
                              tv_black().withOpacity(0.2),
                              // tv_black().withOpacity(0.5),
                              // tv_black().withOpacity(0.4),
                              // tv_black().withOpacity(0.3),
                              // tv_black().withOpacity(0.2),
                              // tv_black().withOpacity(0.1),
                              // Colors.transparent,
                              Colors.transparent,
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            final metadata = state!.currentSource!.tag as MediaItem;
            return _currentAudio(
              metadata,
              _player,
            );
            // return Container();
          },
        )
```

I dedugging using a sumsang galaxy A03 Andriod version 12. I am using the latest version of just audio and just_audio_background

```
just_audio: ^0.9.36
just_audio_background: ^0.0.1-beta.11
```

But when i actually hard code the values, as in

```
final audioSource = AudioSource.uri(
  Uri.parse("http://<ip>/media/audio/078Surah_an_naba_oXGPBwK.mp3"),
  tag: MediaItem(
    id: "1",
    album: "categro",
    title: "title",
    artUri: Uri.parse(
      "http://<ip>/media/tv/thumb_nails/aUDIO_sOON_2-01_DGikdsa.jpg",
    ),
  ),
);
```

then it does not crash.

Mind you I also tried initializing the AudioSource from the second page it was still crashing.

Been stuck on this for days! any help is welcome.

Comment: `just_audio` does not support HTTP URLs by default. That could be a possible reason for your app crashing.

Checkout the docs: https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio#:~:text=Note%3A%20By%20default%2C%20headers%20are%20implemented%20via%20a%20local%20HTTP%20proxy%20which%20on%20Android%2C%20iOS%20and%20macOS%20requires%20non%2DHTTPS%20support%20to%20be%20enabled

Comment: I have tried with https too. But it still crashes. But still hard coding the values does not crash. It works fine. I really do know the issues.
final audioSource = AudioSource.uri(
            Uri.parse(
                "http://domain_name/media/audio/078Surah_an_naba_oXGPBwK.mp3"),
            tag: MediaItem(
              id: 5.toString(),
              album: "test",
              title: "title",
              artUri: Uri.parse(
                "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg",
              ),
            ),
          );

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a platform specific code mentioned in the documentation.

> If you wish to connect to non-HTTPS URLs (typically HTTP), also add the following attribute to the application element:

```
<application ... android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

There are other network security config you can include to make your IP work for just audio. You can refer to the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio#platform-specific-configuration)

Comment: I have already set usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the manifest file.

Comment: What about network security config? Did you try that one?